# how to ser read unread message in custom listview in android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

i have one Custom list view in android in which i set base adapter, in one row of custom list view i have two texview. now i set the text of these two textviews from json parsing. i want to display read unread messages. how can i achieve this?

following is my code for adapter class,

```
public class ImageAdapter_Notification extends BaseAdapter
{


    //Serch
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    //Serch

    String[] message;
    String [] id;
    String[]date;

public ImageAdapter_Notification(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

public ImageAdapter_Notification(Context context,String [] message, String [] id,String[]date)
{
    mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); 
    this.message=message;
    this.id=id;
    this.date=date;

}



public class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_top,txt_large,txt_date;

}

public int getCount() {
    //return array_str_logo.length;
    return message.length;


}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_notification, null);

            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml

            holder.txt_top = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_top);
            holder.txt_large=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_large);
            holder.txt_date=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);

            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
    /*  if(position%2==0)
        {
        holder.txt_top.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else
        {


        }
    */  holder.txt_top.setText(id[position]);
        holder.txt_large.setText(message[position]);
        holder.txt_date.setText(date[position]);    



        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent=new Intent(Notification_Activity.this,Notification_Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("from", id[position]);
                intent.putExtra("message",  message[position].toString());
                intent.putExtra("date",  date[position].toString());
            //  Log.i("message", message[position].toString());
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });



        return convertView;
    }


}// End of ImageAdapterclass
```

how can i text color for read- unread message.
any help would be appreciated heartly.

Comment: I hope those messages are coming from a database, aren't they?

Comment: no data are coming from server through json parsing.

Comment: On server side, is there a database to save messages?

Comment: @Nizam...yes there is a database to save messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a database at server side to maintain messages, then adding an extra column for this purpose will solve the problem. Say, column `Status Integer Default 0`

Now, inside your `getView()`, check this value and set corresponding color.

When user reads the message, change the value in the table to 1.

Comment: you mean to say if user read message at that time android app should post something which updates the status in database? if so then that message will automatically consider as a read for other users as well. isn't it?

Comment: So the message is not for a particular user?

Comment: No. For Every User who installs the app

Comment: Then you have to design another table (with foreign key) for this purpose. And for each user, there should be an entry.

Comment: Thanks this will help me a lot.